# How to distinguish between PowerShell remote ISE and remote console?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to distinguish between if a PowerShell script is being run via a remote session started in an ISE or a remote session started in a console?

We would like to set some of the RawUI variables and need to distinguish between ISE and console. Locally, Test-Path variable:global:psISE does the trick, but when connecting remotely from an ISE this returns false and our UI adjustments fail.

Test-Path variable:global:psISE

The session is from an ISE it is just from a remote ISE.

Comment: PowerShell support disconnected sessions. You can start remote session from console, disconnect from session, and then connect to that session from ISE.